# Coil Kotlin Uri to Bitmap throws null pointer exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-bitmap

Trying to convert a `Uri` image file to `Bitmap` in Kotlin fails with a Null Pointer exception. How can I fix this?

```
var bitmap = remember {  mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null)}

LaunchedEffect(key1 = "tobitmap") {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        bitmap.value = uriToBitmap(
            context,
            shoppingListScreenViewModel.state.value.imageUri
        )
    }
}

Image(
    bitmap = bitmap.value?.asImageBitmap()!!, //Throws exception here
    contentDescription = ""
)

private suspend fun uriToBitmap(context: Context, uri: Uri?): Bitmap {

    val loader = ImageLoader(context)
    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(uri)
        .allowHardware(false) // Disable hardware bitmaps.
        .build()

    val result = (loader.execute(request) as SuccessResult).drawable
    val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

    val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
        bitmap, 80, 80, true);

    return resizedBitmap
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bitmap = bitmap.value?.asImageBitmap()!!, //Throws exception here
```

not-null assertion is not a good way to handle this.

Your possible options are either display Image with

```
bitmap?.value?.asImageBitmap()?.let{ imageBitmap->
   Image(...)
}
```

and wait for bitmap to be created while you display nothing

or display preferably a `Composable` for loading or `Image` with placeholder.

```
if(bitmap.value!= null) {
  Image(...)
} else {
 // Your loading Composable
}
```

Another option is to use `SubcomposeAsyncImage` which has slots for Loading, Error and Success Composable slots so you can pass your Composables inside these slots.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
var bitmap = remember {  mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null)}
```

Here, `bitmap.value` will be `null`.

```kotlin
Image(
    bitmap = bitmap.value?.asImageBitmap()!!, //Throws exception here
    contentDescription = ""
)
```

Here, `bitmap.value?.asImageBitmap()` will be `null`, since `bitmap.value` is `null`. As a result, you will crash with a `NullPointerException` as soon as you execute this code.

*Eventually*, `bitmap.value` will not be `null`, courtesy of your `LaunchedEffect`, but that will take some time. You need to rework your composable to be able to work prior to that point in time.